# is it possible to set stylish jquery scroll on textarea?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to set stylish jquery scroll on textarea?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jquery textarea scroll</title>
<style type="text/css">
.my_textarea{
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    overflow:auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<textarea name="txt_area" class="my_textarea"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ and it works quite nice

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea
{
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #444;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #fff;
    scrollbar-face-color: #444;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #fff;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #444;
    scrollbar-track-color: #444;
}
```

Comment: then try [this](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jQuery plugin http://www.rshahin.com/jquery-plugin-to-style-scrollbars-cross-browser-compatible/